# How to create a responsive hamburger menu with Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, media-queries

I'm working on a simple project and trying to create a responsive navbar with hamburger menu, with the menu to the left when on devices with max-width at 480px. This is what I have so far and not sure what I'm doing wrong. I've tried targeting different classes within the navbar and dropdown, but nothing has worked. Sorry if I've posted wrong or wrong format. I'm still new to Stack and any help is always appreciated. Thank you!

**HTML:**

```
<nav>
<!--Navbar Start-->
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 border-bottom border-dark">
            <div class="page-header text-center">
                <h1>Genealogist</h1>
            </div>
            <ul class="nav">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" href="index.html">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Learn More</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#contact">Contact</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown ml-md-auto">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink"
                        data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown link</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a> <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another
                            action</a> <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-divider">
                        </div> <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    </nav>
    <!--Navbar End-->
```

**CSS:**

```
html, body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    
}

.dropdown {
    
}

img:hover {
    transform: translateX(60px);
    
}

.form {
    padding-top: 50px;
}

main {
    background-color: lightblue;
    border-bottom: solid black 2px;
    background-size: cover;
    
    
}

.experience ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}


/* Width Covers 0px-480px */
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) { 
    nav ul { display: none; }
    nav select { display: inline-block; }
}

/* Width Covers 481px-768px */
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    body {
      
    }

}

/* Width Covers 769px-1025px (and greater) */
@media screen and (min-width: 1025px) {
  body {
    
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no requirement of media-queries here as bootstrap navbars are pretty responsive! You just need to make use of the right classes at the right places. Code-

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<div class = "container">
  <br><h1 class="text-center">Genealogist</h1>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light justify-content-center">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"></a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler align-center" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarText" aria-controls="navbarText" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarText">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Learn More</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div class="dropdown show">
        <a class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown link
        </a>

        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. So are you saying media queries aren't used as much with bootstrap? I was just told to do it for our project to use media queries, so I guess I'll have to rebuild the navbar for that. Pretty much need to build a responsive navbar using media queries that is responsive and turns into a hamburger menu on screens at 480px